# How to return an jsonarray in BeanShell PostProcessor for next testcase in jmeter

Tags: jmeter

After I get a list like this:

```
[{

    "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b8000680",
},{ 

    "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bc",      
    "object": {
            "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bd",
         }
}]
```

In the BeanShell PostProcessor I have code to return an list Id like this:

```
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import java.util.*; 

String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); 
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser(); 
JSONArray GroupList = (JSONArray) parser.parse(response); 
Iterator i = GroupList.iterator; 
JSONArray GroupIds = new JSONArray(); 
while (i.hasNext()) 
 { 
 JSONObject objGroup = (JSONObject) i.next(); 
 GroupIds.push(objGroup.get("id")); 
 } 
vars.putObject("GroupIds",GroupIds);
```

For the next test element, I create the foreach Loop controller to loop the `GroupIds`, but I see in the log, it has error like this:

> jmeter.util.BeanShellInterpreter: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.JSONArray; import
>   org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Cannot access field:
>   iterator, on object:[{
>       "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b8000680",
>       "name": "Companies",
>       "description": "Contacts of companies",
>       "type": "Group",
>       "created_at": "2015-07-22T03:27:05Z",
>       "updated_at": "2015-07-23T02:45:02Z",
>       "dominant_gender": "unknown",
>       "average_age": "?" }, {
>       "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bc",
>       "name": "Subscription",
>       "description": "Subscription",
>       "type": "Subscriptions::SubscriptionList",
>       "average_age": "?",
>       "subscription": {
>           "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bd",
>           "name": "Subcription 1",
>           "form_ids": ["5526430cba411ff8c30001cd"]
>       } }]
>
> jmeter.extractor.BeanShellPostProcessor: Problem in BeanShell script
>   org.apache.jorphan.util.JMeterException: Error invoking bsh method:
>   eval  Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import
>   org.json.simple.JSONObject; import org.json.simple.JSONArray; import
>   org. . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Cannot access field:
>   iterator, on object:[{
>       "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b8000680",
>       "name": "Companies",
>       "description": "Contacts of companies",
>       "type": "Group",
>       "created_at": "2015-07-22T03:27:05Z",
>       "updated_at": "2015-07-23T02:45:02Z",
>       "dominant_gender": "unknown",
>       "average_age": "?" }, {
>       "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bc",
>       "name": "Subscription",
>       "description": "Subscription",
>       "type": "Subscriptions::SubscriptionList",
>       "average_age": "?",
>       "subscription": {
>           "id": "55af0d89ba411ff8b80006bd",
>           "name": "Subcription 1",
>           "form_ids": ["5526430cba411ff8c30001cd"]
>       } }]

What is the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are few issues with your code:

1. `Iterator i = GroupList.iterator;` - parentheses are required as `iterator` is a method, not field.
2. `GroupIds.push(objGroup.get("id"));` - change `push` to `add`, there is no `push` method

Full working code:

```
String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString();
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray GroupList = (JSONArray) parser.parse(response);
Iterator i = GroupList.iterator();
JSONArray GroupIds = new JSONArray();
while (i.hasNext()) {
    JSONObject objGroup = (JSONObject) i.next();
    GroupIds.add(objGroup.get("id"));
}
vars.putObject("GroupIds", GroupIds);
```

By the way, it isn't very recommended to use Beanshell for under high load as it is not very efficient. For one thread it is OK, but when it comes to immense load - it may become performance bottleneck and may ruin your test. If it is the case - consider switching to [JSR223 PostProcessor](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_PostProcessor) and "groovy" language instead.

A very little change will be required:

- adding groovy-all.jar to JMeter's /lib folder
- substitute all Beanshell test elements to JSR223 with "groovy" engine

See [Beanshell vs JSR223 vs Java JMeter Scripting: The Performance-Off You've Been Waiting For!](https://blazemeter.com/blog/beanshell-vs-jsr223-vs-java-jmeter-scripting-its-performance) article for detailed installation instructions, scripting tips and tricks and different scripting engines performance benchmark.

---

**UPDATE** - generate variables for ForEach Controller:

```
import org.json.simple.parser.JSONParser;
import org.json.simple.JSONArray;
import org.json.simple.JSONObject;

String response = prev.getResponseDataAsString(); 
JSONParser parser = new JSONParser();
JSONArray GroupList = (JSONArray) parser.parse(response);
for (int i = 0; i < GroupList.size(); i++) {
    JSONObject objGroup = (JSONObject) GroupList.get(i);
    vars.put("Group_" + i, objGroup.get("id"));
}
```

Then add a ForEach Controller and configure it as follows:

- Input variable prefix: `Group`
- Start index: `-1`
- Output variable name: `CURRENT_GROUP`
- Add "_" before number - check the box

Use `${CURRENT_GROUP}` where required

Comment: JSR233 does not support groovy, but the BFS support it. by the ways, I am not familiar with groovy, can I use java or javascript ?

Comment: in any ways, I try to used "GroupIds" for next controller but it does not action, in the ForEach Controller I add in input variable prefix like this ${GroupIds} and it does not work at the ForEach Controller

Comment: ForEach controller won't take JSON Array as input. It looks for variables like `var_1`, `var_2`, etc like described [here](https://blazemeter.com/blog/using-regular-expressions-jmeter)

Comment: above data, I want to foreach controller for parent id, so I can not use regular expression extracttor, how can I do that ?

Comment: I've updated the code to demonstrate how you can use group ids in foreach controller. If you are not able to understand the idea from the above link I would suggest quitting IT and becoming a barista